# Synology DS1010+ shows degraded under status

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

As the title says I've got an error on my friend's NAS this evening. Even when I check that disk, it said that it's "abnormal" under smart test but the status shows "Not initialized". Under the storage manager, it shows the option "manage" & when I click it says "repair".

What I would like to know is the if I repair the disk will I loose all the DATA(s) or will those be rebuilt once the repairing is done. Below seen is a screen of what type of RAID that the NAS is on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clicking repair should not harm any data however if the drive is failing SMART tests it's likely the drive should be replaced before the array is repaired.